# Swift ios regex to only allow postive numbers 1 and up

Tags: ios, regex, swift, xcode

I am trying to make a regex that only allows positive numbers **starting from 1 and up**
E.g.:

```
1 // pass
23 // pass
023 // fail
00234 // fail
2340 // pass
```

So far I have this `"^0[0-9].*$"` but this will only allow numbers starting with 0 which I dont want.

So how can I make a regex that only supports positive numbers/integers

Comment: You're better off just parsing the number and checking it.

Comment: How is `023` not a positive number?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Sry I will edit. What I mean is starting from 1 and up

Comment: Where are you getting the number from?

Comment: Are your strings always numbers with possible `0` padding?

Comment: Don't conflate regex with knowing _anything_ about _numbers_, it doesn't. As far as numbers, most languages think 000000000000001 is a number  >= 1. If you just want a regex, it's simply `^(?!0)\d+`

Comment: [`^[1-9][0-9]*$`](http://iswift.org/playground?7IIueJ) is not a good choice, I'd use `"^[1-9][0-9]*\\z"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why do I need to add *\\z ?

Comment: Because the `$` can match before the final newline in the string. `\z` only matches at the *very* end of the string. It is not always that important, but when you are validating, you'd want to make sure nothing but your expected symbols are allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I mean is starting from 1 and up

Regex for a decimal number that doe not start in `0` is as follows:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Note that this regex will match sequences of digits that could not be represented as built-in numeric types in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Use following regular expression to input the numbers starting from 1 to 9

"^[1-9][0-9]*$"

Comment: This will work correctly if you add `\A` and `\z` anchors. `"\\A[1-9][0-9]*\\z";`.

Comment: Works correctly with `^$`. Newlines are never interpreted as part of a string after it is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

If your strings contain only the number with possible `0` padding, use `hasPrefix`

```
let str = "00234"
let match = !str.hasPrefix("0") // false
```